# proving that an equation $\frac{f}{g} $ is uniformly continous

Tags: calculus

I have a calculus question I falied to prove. I tried to prove it from the definition.

Given $|f(x)|\leq M\qquad|g(x)|\geq m\qquad m>0\qquad M>0$,

f and g are uniformly coninous for all x in a set I.
prove that $\frac{f}{g}$ is uniforml continous.

Comment: Is $I$ an interval? Is there where you want to show $f/g$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: @user2566092 Yes and Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** $$ \left| \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-\frac{f(y)}{g(y)} \right| = \left| \frac{f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x)}{g(x)g(y)} \right| = \left| \frac{f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(y)+f(y)g(y)-f(y)g(x)}{g(x)g(y)} \right| \leq  \frac{1}{|g(x)|}\left|f(x)-f(y)\right| + \frac{|f(y)|}{|g(x)g(y)|}\left|g(y)-g(x) \right| $$

Then use the bounds and uniform continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$f(x+\delta)/g(x+\delta) - f(x)/g(x) = \frac{g(x)f(x+\delta) - f(x)g(x+\delta)}{g(x)g(x+\delta)}$$

where $|f| \leq M$ (you can choose $\delta$ to make the numerator as close zero as you want) and $|g| \geq m$ (so you can put a universal upper bound of $1/m^2$ on the denomintator).